# JScrollpanel not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-jscrollpane

I am trying to figure out why Kelvin Luck's [JScrollPanel](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) isn't working for me. The scroll bar is showing up, however, its not showing the overflow items. You can see my page and see what I mean by going to http://glassyan.glassyan.com/

It is only showing 6 items, even though there are 10 items. The scroll bar shows up, but its not letting me scroll. I can only ever see the 6 items. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TimeClock.css, remove height: 100%; on line 10:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This line makes your scrollbar take all available space, and breaks the script.

To fix your footer, add:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, but it breaks my footer for some reason. But you fixed the jquery jscrollpane issue. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at my original answer, where I now added fix for your footer.

Answer (score 0):

Give a height to class `.login_page .center`